# Send email from ASMX web service

Tags: c#, .net, asmx

Recently somebody answered me on this site, that this method can send email from .net application:

```
public static void SendEmail(bool isHTML, string toEmail, string fromEmail, string subject, string message)
{
    var sm = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru");
    sm.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyLogin", "MyPass");
    var m = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail) { Subject = subject, Body = message };
    if (isHTML)
    {
        m.IsBodyHtml = true;
    }
    sm.Send(m); // SmtpException
}
```

It is true. But now I want to use this method from Asp.Net WebService, but I have SmtpException at last string. Why? And do I send email from web service.

Comment: SmtpException usually indicates a delivery failure of some sort, ie. the SMTP server you're trying to deliver to rejected your email.  What's the exception?

Comment: @miksayer What is the StatusCode property?

Comment: @CodingGorilla System.Net.Mail.SmtpStatusCode.GeneralFailure

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is not with your code, rather the transaction with the SMTP server is failing for some reason.  If you  have access to the SMTP server, check its logs.  Otherwise you might have to use a sniffer like WireShark to figure it out.

To verify this, you can try using a different mail server, assuming you have proper access to that server it should send the mail properly.

Comment: But when I used this method and this smtp server from desktop application two days ago, it worked.

Comment: The technical description of the SmtpStatusCode.GeneralFailure is:  GeneralFailure The transaction could not occur. You receive this error when the specified SMTP host cannot be found.  So it sounds like you're not getting DNS resolution, or your web server cannot properly communicate with the SMTP server (firewall maybe?).  Either way, the problem is not a coding one, your code is fine.

Comment: No, I don't have any firewall on my computer. I don't understand why it works in desktop app but doesn't work in web app.

Comment: The only thing I can do is suggest using a utility such as WireShark (http://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor the network traffic so you can see what's going on in the SMTP session.

Comment: Are you running your web app from your desktop?  If you're running the web app on a hosted server, that could be the difference.